# Cant put variable(string) in javascript innerhtml

Tags: javascript, html

How can I quote the `meni` variable correctly in the code below?  It's currently producing `cancel(menu)` instead of `cancel('menu')`

```
var meni='menu';

document.getElementById("modify_table").rows.item(counter).cells[4].innerHTML="<a href='javascript:cancel("+meni+")'><b style='color:red;'>Cancel</b></a>";
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: no, this code gives `uncaught ReferenceError: meni is not defined...`

Comment: `meni !== menu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("modify_table"). rows.item(counter).cells[4].innerHTML="<a href='javascript:cancel(\""+meni+"\")'><b style='color:red;'>Cancel</b></a>";
```

Comment: I tried that, but it gives " cancel(  "  I dont know how.

Comment: Fixed it.  I should have tested it, but you didn't supply the html

Answer (score 0):

You can have the double quote, `"`, not take its normal effect of terminating the string by preceding it with a backslash `\`. This is called [escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation).

Simplified version that is easier to see in a snippet:

```js
var meni='menu';

document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML=
  "<a href='javascript:cancel(\""+meni+"\")'><b style='color:red;'>Cancel</b></a>";
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Your actual requested code:

```
var meni='menu';

document.getElementById("modify_table"). rows.item(counter).cells[4].innerHTML="<a href='javascript:cancel(\""+meni+"\")'><b style='color:red;'>Cancel</b></a>";
```